# Bulkcopy inserts with DBCC CheckIdent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy, batch-processing, dbcc

Our team needs to insert a cruel amount of data into our SQL Server 2008 database. We're looking for a good solution. Now we came up with one, but I have doubts with it, simply because it doesn't feel right. So I'm asking here if this seems like a good solution. Extra challange is that it's a peer-to-peer replicated database over 4 servers! :)

Imagine we have 1 million rows to insert

1. Start transaction
2. Increase current ident value on a table with 1 million
3. Have a DataSet/DataTable ready with 1 million rows and the correct ids
4. BulkCopy the data into the database
5. Commit transaction

Is this a good solution, might we get into concurrency issues, have too large transactions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you'll only get problems (as far as I can see, so there might be things I overlook!) if the database is online and users can insert rows into that table. Increasing the identity value for new rows on the meta-level simply means that the next row inserted by the system will use that number, so if you bump it with 1 million, it means you reserved those numbers up front.

Identity columns are 'nice' but have the side effect that they're not transferable. So if you have to migrate the data to another DB, realize that you likely have to adjust the data inserted to match the database you insert it in (as that's the scope of the data which means identity fields could collide with rows already in the table).

If this is a one-time affair, it might work out. If you're planning to do this regularly, I'd look into a more higher-level migration system where you migrate the data to new identity values or use guid's with NEWSEQUENTIALID() so you get proper checked indexes and also  unique, transferable id's.